# How can I read a big CSV file without Memory exhausted?

Tags: php, csv, file-get-contents, explode

I have a CSV file which is over 16 MB big.

When I read it with this:

```
$exportString = @file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($contextOptions)
```

I simply want to make an echo on:

```
$data=explode(';', $exportString);
echo $data[0];
```

Then this message appears in my browser:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in....
```

And after this, I want to import it in MySQL DB.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *php.ini* file you can increase the allowed memory size

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Or at the top of the script put:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```

Or if you don't have access to *php.ini*, create a *.htaccess* file in the root and put

```
php_value memory_limit = "512M"
```

---

**EDIT**: 268435456 bytes = 256MB, so make it larger!

Keep in mind, having a gigantic memory limit isn't really a substitute for writing good code.  It would be better to split it into chunks using `file_get_contents` additional parameters `offset` and `length`.

---

## Splitting would not be a trivial task

**But, here is a simple algoritm on how you might be able to do it!**

```
1. Initialize an empty string
  (begin a loop)
2. Grab a chunk from your file and append that to the string
3. Search for the last \n character in that string (MAKE SURE IT ISN'T PART OF DATA)
  a. If \n doesn't exist, continue
  b. If it does, grab the first substring up to that point and process that.
     Once finished grab the rest of substring assign it to your initial string.
  (loop until finished)
4. If there is data in the string left, do processing on that as well.
```

**Now, the algorithm to find the last "\n" in a string**

```
1. Initialize a variable called $inString = false and 
2. Initialize a variable $newLinePos = -1
3. Loop through each character of the string
  (begin loop)
  a. If the current charater is a double quote (")
     AND the character before IS NOT a backslash (\)
     Then set $inString = !$inString;
  b. If $inString Then continue;
  c. If the current character is the newline (\n)
     Then set $newLinePos to the index of the current character
  (end loop)
4. If $newLinePos == -1 then we have not found any valid \n and we need to grab more
   Otherwise, go on with the next part as perscribed above
```

Comment: But how can I split the file? ANd how do I know where exactly to split the file?

Comment: Above is an algorithm.  I didn't give code because that's the fun part!